# Linear Layout overlapping with Scroll view and other Linear Layout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, toolbar

Recently i have encounterd a problem. My linear layout where my edit text and image button is in is overlapping with my toolbar and my scroll view. I've tried other things like layout_below etc and nothing worked. Groupchat.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".GroupChatActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/group_chat_bar_layout"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_layout">
</include>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/my_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/group_chat_bar_layout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/myLinearLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/group_chat_text_display"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_group_message"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Write message..." />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/send_message_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/send_message" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how the preview of the groupchat.xml file looks in Android Studio:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLCoh.png)

This was how the app looked with this code.
[This are the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3vWu.jpg)

Just in case, this is the code of my toolbar: Appbarlayout.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
```

It in a seperate xml because i'm using it for other activities in my app to thats why theres ang include in th Groupchat.xml

ALSO I AM FOLLOWING THIS TUTORILA. I suggest you go ther and see it because that is what i followed.

[go to this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RL85tdhCEU&t=607s)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with layout placements. your LinearLayout with ID: myLinearLayout is not aligned anywhere in RelativeLayout that's why it is getting rendered on top of the screen. make following changes and your good to go.

in your LinearLayout with id: myLinearLayout, add this line:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/group_chat_bar_layout"
```

this line to LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/group_chat_bar_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_group_message"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Write message..." />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/send_message_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bkg" />

</LinearLayout>`
```